# Plot relation between y and multiple x?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I can use the following to plot the pairwise scatter plots.

```
pairs(mtcars)
```

How to just plot the plots of one response variable wrt to the other explanatory variables?

Answer (score 2):

**1) ggplot2** Convert to long form and use ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>% 
 pivot_longer(-mpg) %>%
 ggplot(aes(value, mpg)) + 
   geom_point() +
   facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free")
```

[image: screenshot]

**2) lattice** or with xyplot from lattice:

```
library(lattice)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>%
  pivot_longer(-mpg) %>%
  xyplot(mpg ~ value | name, ., scales = list(relation = "free"))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Lattice looks especially neat imo

Answer (score 1):

Using `base` R:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,5))
for(i in 2:ncol(df))
{
    plot(df[,i],df$mpg,xlab=colnames(df)[i],ylab='MPG')
}
```

[image: MPG vs. Other Attributes]

You can also add other parameters for the `plot` (e.g. `main` for headings, `col` for colours, `type` for the type of the plot)

Try running `?par` in `R` to get all the parameters available for the `plot` function.

EDIT: A more elegant way of doing the plot is (as mentioned by @G. Grothendieck in the comments):

```
opar <- par(mfrow=3:4, mar = c(4, 4, 1, 1))
for(nm in names(mtcars)[-1]) plot(mtcars[c(nm, "mpg")])
par(opar)
```

Comment: Suggest this variation: `opar <- par(mfrow=3:4, mar = c(4, 4, 1, 1));
for(nm in names(mtcars)[-1]) plot(mtcars[c(nm, "mpg")]);
par(opar)`